# Converting .Net 1.0 to 2.0 causes System.TypeInitializationException error

Tags: c#, asp.net, enterprise-library

I have converted my .Net 1.0 project to .Net 2.0 and fixed all the bugs related to conversion. My project build succeeded and loaded good in the browser, but when the code tries to access the database, through 
`Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()`;

I get the error in my code here

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database db = 
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
```

I copied the same Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary dlls from .Net 1.0 version to 2.0 assembly. Is that causing the issue ?

I am getting the below error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseFactory' threw an
>   exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationException:
>   Unrecognized attribute 'type'
>   (C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config
>   line 32)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.ConfigurationFile.ReadSectionGroup(XmlTextReader
>   reader, String configKey)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.ConfigurationFile.ReadConfigSections(XmlTextReader
>   reader, String configKey)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.ConfigurationFile.ReadConfiguration(XmlTextReader
>   reader)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.ConfigurationFile.Load(String
>   filename)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.LoadMetaConfiguration(String
>   configurationFile)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.ConfigurationManager..ctor()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_Current()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetCurrentContext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseProviderFactory..ctor()
>   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseFactory..cctor()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()

Comment: A code snippet of where the exception is thrown would help a lot.

Comment: I'd imagine the line *Unrecognized attribute 'type' (C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config line 32)* is a bit of a clue.